# Eclipse and Codesourcery for ARM generate very large binary

Tags: eclipse, arm, cross-compiling, binaries

I'm writing firmware for TM4C1231H6PZ now. Some time ago I was helped to set-up IDE and toolchain, that were generating neat and working binaries for my project, ~8 kB large. After that, I did some directory moving and so on, and now the same IDE, working with the same project (I have restored whole project directory from archive) generates binary 520 Mb large, which is obviously wrong.

Looking into new binary, I see that there is code from 00000000 to 0000079b, after that there are only NULLs, and then some code from 20000000 to 2000002b. I believe that it has to be some code intended for SRAM, but I don't know what to do with it. I tried to just delete code starting from 20000000, but the resulting binary doesn't work on MCU.

May somebody help me to repair my IDE+toolchain to generate normal binaries as before?

I use Eclipse Kepler 2.0.2, Codesourcery Lite for ARM Toolchain (arm-2013.11-24-arm-none-eabi.exe installer) and TivaWare (SW-TM4C-2.1.0.12573.exe).

Here's my linker script file:

```
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 16K
    SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 32K
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        _text = .;
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata)
        *(.rodata*)
        _etext = .;
    } > FLASH

    /* C++ initialization and finalization data */
    .preinit_array :
    {
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
        KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
    } >FLASH
    .init_array :
    {
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
        KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
        KEEP (*(.init_array*))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
    } >FLASH
    .fini_array :
    {
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
        KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
        PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
    } >FLASH

    .data : AT(ADDR(.text) + SIZEOF(.text) + SIZEOF(.preinit_array) + SIZEOF(.init_array) + SIZEOF(.fini_array))
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _data = .;
        *(.data)
        *(.data*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _edata = .;
    } > SRAM

    . = ALIGN(4);
    .bss :
    {
        _bss = .;
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _ebss = .;
    } > SRAM
}
```

Comment: Generate a map file, and see what the symbol at address 0000000 is.  You have introduced an 'alien' section or an unknown object file.  Maybe the linker file had absolute object paths previously.

Comment: Show us the Linker script file.

Comment: you created a binary format file right.  instead of using elf, that is exactly the expected result a file about 0x20000000 bytes in size plus a little.  dont build it as a binary image but as an elf or coff or intel hex or srec, etc.

Comment: Added ld file to original post. @Turbo

Comment: Yes, but as I said binaries generated from the same project were ~8 kB large before, which looks more suitable for 256 kB FLASH that I have. Yes, hex file is of right size, but unfortunately I can only program MCU using bin file. @dwelch

Comment: that is before you likely didnt have any variables in .data.  As soon as you have some items at 0x00000 and some at 0x20000000 the .bin file needs to pad in between meaning the file is 0x20000000+some  remove the variables in .data and then you only need the small amount.  also, likely not, but there may be csrs in between which you dont want to zero if you were to load a file like that

Comment: this has been asked and answered at SO before please search next time

Comment: I would be surprised if the only file format supported by your microcontrollers tools is a binary memory image, if that is the case find alternate, realistic, tools.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere your code contains initial values or program code to be placed in RAM. You need to check your linker map file to figure out the name of this segment.

Let's say, you'll find

```
.ramfunc  0x123
    0x20000000
```

In this case you need to add this section to your .data segment by adding

```
*(.data)
*(.data*)
*(.ramfunc) <-- this line
```

to your linker script.

The data segment will be placed in flash and copied to RAM by the initialization code before main() is called.